# Subset of Measurable Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume we have  a measurable set $E$ with positive measure $ \mu (E) > 0$, which means this set is infinite . Let $A\subset E$ and $E-A$ is finite . My Question: Is $A$ measurable ?

Comment: $A$ can not be finite since $E$ is infinite and $E-A$ is finite .

Comment: Is $E-A$ measurable? then what about $E-(E-A)$?

Comment: Of course $E-A$ is measurable $ \mu (E-A)=0$ .I think $ E-(E-A)=A$ is also measurable. Is I am correct?

Comment: $E-A$ has measure zero, if the $\mu$ is not complete then it may not contain all the sets which have measure zero. But it can be extended to such a measure. So as well you may say that it is measurable. Notice that the measurable sets constitute a $\sigma-$algebra. And the operation $E-A$ is just $E\bigcap A^{c}$ where $(\cdot)^{c}$ is just the complement. Which makes you correct.

Comment: Thank you... If you post your comment again as an answer so can I put it as best answer. thanks again.

Comment: Is this on the real line with the Borel sigma-algebra and the Lebesgue measure? Otherwise, I fail to grasp some arguments in the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $A\subseteq E$ it follows that $A^c\supseteq E^c$.  Thus $A^c=E^c\cup (E\cap A^c)$, and this is measurable, being the union of $E^c$, which is measurable being the complement of $E$ which is assumed to be measurable, and $E\cap A^c=E\smallsetminus A$, which is also measurable being finite.  It follows that $A=(A^c)^c$ is measurable.

Recall that the measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra, i.e.,

(a) the whole space and the empty set are measurable,

(b) the complement of any measurable set is measurable, and

(c) if $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ is a countable collection of measurable sets (finite or infinite) then their union $\bigcup_i A_i$ is measurable.

In particular the union of two measurable sets is measurable (by (c)), and any finite
(indeed countable) set is measurable, being the union of the singletons it contains (and singletons are measurable being closed sets).